# Creating an Intent from a Fragment and passing data back to that Fragment from the Intent activity (Tabbed App)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent

I have abit of a problem and it seems I have not been able to solve it via search.
I have noticed there are other solutions however when i pass a bundle via transaction the program stops working and all other solutions have failed so far.

Note this is a tabbed application.

What i am attempting to do.

1. Click Button which opens up a new Intent expandable listView
2. select item on new Intent on Expandable list view
3. Pass data from the Expandable list activity back to the fragment

code is below

MainActivity.java (nothing special here)

```
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 1:
                    return exercises.newInstance();
                case 2:
                    return MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 3:
                    return MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 4:
                    return MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                //case two for later
            /*case 2:
                return AnotherFragment.newInstance();*/
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 5 total pages.
            return 5;
        }


    }


}
```

exerciseList.Java (Expandable listView class, does not include custom adapter)

```
package com.example.rowan.assignment1;
/* Intent activity created for used to select exercise from expandable List menu to save space on other App pages
*/


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class exerciseList extends AppCompatActivity {
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //get the listView
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        //set the data
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String muscle = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
                String exercise = listDataChild.get( listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        childPosition);
                //On ListView child click, return to fragment with data


                //Previous attempts
                /*Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("muscle", muscle);
                bundle.putString("exercise", exercise);


                startActivity(intent);

                //another attempt
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("muscle", muscle);
                args.putString("exercise", exercise);
                exercises fragment = new exercises();
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.tabItem2, fragment);
                transaction.commit();

                //yet another
                exercises fragment = (exercises) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.tabItem2);
                fragment.setData(muscle,exercise);
                finish();

                //4th attempt
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out;
                    store f = new store(muscle, exercise);
                    out=openFileOutput("exfile", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                    oout.writeObject(f);
                    oout.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                finish();
                */

                return false;
            }
        });
    }


private void prepareListData(){
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        //adding parent data
        listDataHeader.add("Chest");
        listDataHeader.add("Back");
        listDataHeader.add("Shoulders");
        listDataHeader.add("Quadriceps");
        listDataHeader.add("Hamstring");
        listDataHeader.add("Biceps");
        listDataHeader.add("Triceps");

        List<String> chestEx = new ArrayList<String>();
        chestEx.add("Push Ups");
        chestEx.add("Bench Press");
        chestEx.add("Cable Crossover");
        chestEx.add("Pec Deck");
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), chestEx);

        List<String> backEx = new ArrayList<String>();
        backEx.add("Pull Ups");
        backEx.add("Chin Ups");
        backEx.add("Lat Pull-downs");
        backEx.add("Dumbbell Row");
        backEx.add("Dumbbell Shrugs");
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), backEx);

        List<String> shoulderEx = new ArrayList<String>();
        shoulderEx.add("Overhead Dumbbell Press");
        shoulderEx.add("Overhead Machine Press");
        shoulderEx.add("Arnold Press");
        shoulderEx.add("Upright Rows");
        shoulderEx.add("Rear Deltoid Rows/Raises/Flyes");
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), shoulderEx);

        List<String> quadricepsEx = new ArrayList<String>();
        quadricepsEx.add("Squats");
        quadricepsEx.add("Lunges");
        quadricepsEx.add("Step-ups");
        quadricepsEx.add("Leg Press");
        quadricepsEx.add("Leg Extensions");
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), shoulderEx);

        List<String> hamstringEx = new ArrayList<String>();
        hamstringEx.add("Deadlifts");
        hamstringEx.add("Hyperextensions");
        hamstringEx.add("Glute/Ham raises");
        hamstringEx.add("Leg Curls");
        hamstringEx.add("Cable Pull-Throughs");
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), hamstringEx);

        List<String> bicepEx = new ArrayList<String>();
        bicepEx.add("Cable Curls");
        bicepEx.add("Machine Curls");
        bicepEx.add("Dumbbell Curls");
        bicepEx.add("Barbell Curls");
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), bicepEx);

        List<String> tricepEx = new ArrayList<String>();
        tricepEx.add("Dips");
        tricepEx.add("Bench Press");
        tricepEx.add("Close Grip Push-Ups");
        tricepEx.add("Tricep Extensions");
        tricepEx.add("Skull Crushers");
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), tricepEx);
    }


}
```

exercises.Java (Fragment class [Tabbed app])

```
package com.example.rowan.assignment1;



import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class exercises extends Fragment {


    Button exButton;
    Button update;
    String muscle, exercise;

    public exercises() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercises, container, false);


        /*muscle = getArguments().getString("muscle");
        exercise = getArguments().getString("exercise");*/



        // Insert onCreate code here
        exButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.exbutton);


        /*if (muscle == "Chest") {
            exButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.chest);
            exButton.setText(exercise);
        }*/

        exButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // on click move to intent with expandable listView for selection
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), exerciseList.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    public static exercises newInstance() {
        exercises fragment = new
                exercises();
        return fragment;
    }
    //Function from failed attempt
    /*public void setData(String m, String e){
        muscle = m;
        exercise = e;
    }*/


}
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, Albiet there is probably a better solution.
I have passed an Intent from exerciseList.Java to MainActivity.Java

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity.class);

                    //Data
                    intent.putExtra("muscle", muscle);
                    intent.putExtra("exercise", exercise);
                    intent.putExtra("frag", 1);

                    startActivity(intent);
```

I then passed that data from MainActivity.Java to exercises.Java (The Fragment)

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        int frag = intent.getIntExtra("frag",0);
 if (frag == 1){
            muscle = intent.getStringExtra("muscle");
            exercise = intent.getStringExtra("exercise");
            //exercises is menu item 1 (mainActivity is 0)
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(frag);
        }
//Another section of code
 public String getMuscle(){
        return muscle;
    }

    public String getExercise(){
        return exercise;
    }
```

Finally i accessed the data in exercises.Java

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

            muscle = activity.getMuscle();
            exercise = activity.getExercise();
```